# C Memory allocation issue with integer and printing

Tags: c, memory-management

I have a datatype called 'data' which is a void pointer. It's used as an argument for another function, this allowing the programmer to send any datatype as an argument to that specific function.

How do I combine my allocations so I don't have to use 4 different variables and instead only use like 2? I'm talking about **d, d2, dd and dd2**

(OBS! q & q2 are the stack names. Ignore them. The only issue I'm having is with d, d2, dd and dd2.

```
data d = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
*(int *)d = 7;

data d2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
*(int *)d2 = 7;

data dd = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
*(int *)dd = 8;

data dd2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
*(int *)dd2 = 8;

stack_add(q, d); /* Adds an item so the stack is not empty.*/
stack_add(q2, d2); /* Adds an item so the stack is not empty.*/

if (!stack_isEmpty(q)) {

    /* Removes an item and then adds an item from the first stack*/
    stack_remove(q);
    stack_add(q, dd);

    /* Adds an item and then removes one from the second stack*/
    stack_add(q2, dd2);
    stack_remove(q2);
```

How do I combine the allocations so it looks better?

Comment: Why didn't you post `queue_front()`? And which warnings are you getting?

Comment: It's not printing out the integers which I want it to. It's printing out the address or something. Completely messing up my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your allocation is bad because,

   - It violates the DRY principle
   - You don't check for `NULL`
   - The size parameter is bad, it should be `sizeof(*d)`. It's probably ok but since you did not post what `data` is.
2. It appears that you have `typedef`ed a pointer which is bad practice.
3. You should post the code for `stack_firstvalue()` because it might be there where the problem is.

In simple terms, you have very obvious mistakes in your posted code, and you didn't post the interesting code for `stack_firstvalue()`, it's natural to assume that it will contain bugs of course.

Comment: I've managed to fix the errors. My only question is how I can combine the allocation. I know you can do for instance malloc(XXX * sizeof(int));

Comment: What do you mean by combine the allocation?

Comment: I make 4 variable allocations. Is there no way to make the code better?

Comment: What do you really want? An array? You can use subscript notation to do what is called pointer arithmetic, google that and you can learn how.

Comment: Oh I thought it was possible to simplify without a lot of work. If not, then it's good as it's. Thank you very much :)